# Debugging a complex linq query

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am dealing with a complex `linq` query as shown below which raises `System.NullReferenceException` during run time. Unfortunately, visual studio does not provide any other info and I am not able to do a `QuickWatch` on the values to check to see which one is null. Is there a way to debug this kind of queries so that I can see what is wrong ?

```
var dataSource = (from c in session.Query<PortChannel>()
        select
            new PortChannelData
            {
                Location = c.Port.MagazineSlot.SiteMagazine.Site.SiteName,
                MagazineName =
                    String.Format("{0}-{1}", c.Port.MagazineSlot.SiteMagazine.MagazineType.MagazineName,
                        c.Port.MagazineSlot.SiteMagazine.MagazineNo),
                SlotNo = c.Port.MagazineSlot.SlotNo,
                PortNo = c.Port.PortNo,
                Klm = c.Klm,
                StmNo = c.StmNo,
                Label = c.SiteName == null ? null : String.Format("{0}_{1}", c.SiteName, c.E1No),
                ChannelFullName = c.ChannelFullName,
                BscRncPort = c.BscRncPort,
                MgwPort = c.MgwPort,
                ReservedBy = c.ReservedBy,
                CrossFullName = c.CrossConnection == null ? null : c.CrossConnection.ChannelFullName
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?

Comment: Hardly anything complex about this LINQ query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query you can use a `let` keyword to store results of sub-expressions. Then you assign the results when you create a new `PortChannelData` object.

```
var dataSource = 
    (from c in session.Query<PortChannel>()
        let flName = c.CrossConnection == null ? null : c.CrossConnection.ChannelFullName
        let magName = String.Format("{0}-{1}", c.Port.MagazineSlot.SiteMagazine.MagazineType.MagazineName,
                    c.Port.MagazineSlot.SiteMagazine.MagazineNo)
        // and so on
        select new PortChannelData
        {
            MagazineName = magName,
            CrossFullName = flName,
            // ...
        }).ToList();
```

This way when you debug and step into the query (`F11` is a standard Visual Studio shortcut) you will see result of each sub-expression.

Comment: Note the .ToList() call at the end of the query - this overrides the deferred execution, allowing you to step through the code (for more see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556281/2696616)

Comment: So often forget F11 even in complex Linq queries

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before and the following technique helped me alot.

I've defined the extracted values as properties inside my `select` expression, and just before doing the `new ObjectName()` extraction statement, this way when the error happened, visual studio will point me to the specific part which caused the null reference.

consider the following example:

```
var returnNews = reportResult.Select(n =>
            {
                var createdBy = allUsersInfoForReport.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == n.CreatedBy);
                var publishedBy = allUsersInfoForReport.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == n.Publishedby);
                var modifiedBy = allUsersInfoForReport.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == n.LastModifiedBy);

                newsViewCountEntity = newsViewCountCollection.FirstOrDefault(nv => nv.News_ID == n.ID);
                newsCommentsCount = newsCommentsCollection.Count(s => s == n.ID);

                return new ReportItemViewModel()
                {
                    ID = n.ID,

                    AddedBy = createdBy != null ? createdBy.UserName : "",
                    UserSectionName = createdBy != null ? createdBy.RelatedSectionName : "",
                    PublishedBy = publishedBy != null ? publishedBy.UserName : "",
                    LastModifiedBy = modifiedBy != null ? modifiedBy.UserName : "",
                }
});
```

in this example if either of the following properties (`createdBy` - `publishedBy` - `modifiedBy`) is failed to get a valid value, the exception is thrown, but the line is highlighted correctly instead of highlighting the whole LINQ expression.

try to follow the same technique, and let me know of the results.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a breakpoint on the `new PortChannelData` line and debug as usual (the breakpoint will be hit each time the select statement is executed, that is, for each element in `session.Query<PortChannel>()`).

If you had put `select` and `new PortChannelData` on the same line, then setting a breakpoint would put a breakpoint at the start of the Linq query. That breakpoint is only hit once - right before the query is executed - and does not allow you to 'jump into' the query. However, you can change the location of a breakpoint in Visual Studio by right-clicking the red breakpoint dot in the gutter and selecting 'Location...'. Set the location to the starting line and character of `new PortChannelData` and the breakpoint will be put in the select statement.

You can also add conditions to breakpoints, so they will only activate when the condition is met. If `session.Query<PortChannel>()` returns a large number of port channels then a condition that checks if any property or field you're accessing is null can save you some time.